# Aceder variavel dentro de inner class

Tags: java, android

Sou novo em programação android/java e então surgiu me este erro.

```
public class Activity_2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();


    Spinner alvos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.alvos);
    Spinner posicoes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.posicoes);
    ImageButton hit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.hit);
    ImageButton miss = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.miss);

    int contador = getIntent().getIntExtra("cont", 0);
    int sum = getIntent().getIntExtra("targ", 0);
    Integer [] arrayAlvos = new Integer[sum];

    for(int i=1; i<=sum; i++){
        arrayAlvos[i-1]=i;
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrayAlvos);
    alvos.setAdapter(adapter);


    ArrayAdapter pos = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.posicao, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    posicoes.setAdapter(pos);

        hit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(tiro.this);
                alert.setMessage("Certo");
                alert.show();
                contador++;
            }
        });

        miss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(tiro.this);
                alert.setMessage("Errado");
                alert.show();
                contador++;
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Eu criei a variável `int contador = getIntent().getIntExtra("cont", 0);` para saber o limite.

Depois na parte dos botões sempre que eu clicava num botão ele incrementava +1 à variável contador. Só que na parte onde eu tenho `contador++` ele dá-me este erro:

> variable contador is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final android

só que eu não posso mudar para final porque o meu objetivo é mesmo estar sempre a alterar o valor. Alguma solução?!

Answer (score 3):

Variaveis locais não podem ser acessadas por classes aninhadas, a não ser que sejam finais ou sejam declaradas como propriedade da classe principal que comporta a classe aninhada, no seu caso, teria que ser da classe `Activity_2`.

```
public class Activity_2 extends AppCompatActivity {

  private int contador;
...
```

E dentro do método `onCreate` você apenas inicializa ela:

```
contador = getIntent().getIntExtra("cont", 0);
```

Essa seria uma das soluções, outra seria delegar a execução da classe anônima para um método a parte, dentro da sua classe `Activity_2`, passando a `View` como argumento, ou até mesmo criar uma classe que implemente `OnClickListener`, contendo a execução do código, mas pelo seu código, me parecem soluções que não são necessárias.